# Converting a string into an array and returning the values spelled in reverse

Tags: c#, strings, array

I must create a function that accepts a string of names all separated by a comma.

Example: `"Jack,Matthew,John,Sam"`

And return the string of names in the same order but spelled in reverse.

Expected output: `"kcaJ,wehttaM,nhoJ,maS"`

I completed the function with an inner for loop but I would like to know if maybe running a single for loop and inside using a `Linq` function or something similar, would have been better?

```
public string Reverse(string s)
{
    var names = s.Split(",");
    string temp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = names[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            temp += names[i].ElementAt(j);
        }
        temp += i == names.Length - 1 ? "" : ",";
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Anyway I found this problem very simple even though I tried taking my time on it, I found this solution almost immediately so I went with it. I am thinking maybe if I spent more time on it then I could have implemented this with some sort of `Linq` function to reverse the spelling of the names and removed the inner loop.

Really any suggestions for improving this small function is appreciated.

Comment: Did you forget to `return temp`? :)

Comment: Nice catch, forgot that.

Comment: Related : [*"Easy way to reverse each word in a string"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391198/easy-way-to-reverse-each-word-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good code, few suggestions.

---

Instead of having to check each and every time to make sure you can add a `","` or not, add it for all the cases, use [String.TrimEnd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=net-5.0) to remove the extra leading `","`

```cs
            var names = s.Split(",");
            string temp = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = names[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    temp += names[i].ElementAt(j);
                }
                temp += ",";
            }
            return temp.TrimEnd(',');
```

With that change, we have the ability to [foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loop to further improve the readability of the code.

```cs
            string temp = "";
            foreach (var name in s.Split(','))
            {
                for (int j = name.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    temp += name.ElementAt(j);
                }
                temp += ",";
            }
            return temp.TrimEnd(',');
```

That's good. Although we can improve this further by using a better (faster and cleaner) method to reverse the individual names, and that is to use [String.ToCharArray](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-5.0) and [Array.Reverse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=net-5.0)

The idea is to convert the string into a character array, use the inbuilt `Reverse` method to reverse it, add it to `temp`.

```
            string temp = "";
            foreach (var name in s.Split(','))
            {
                char[] NameArray = name.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(NameArray);

                temp = temp + new string(NameArray) + ",";

            }
            return temp.TrimEnd(',');
```

You can also use [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) which is slightly faster

```cs
            StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var word in str.Split(','))
            {
                char[] singlesentence = word.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(singlesentence);
                reversed.Append(singlesentence);
                reversed.Append(",");
            }
            return reversed.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Nitpick:

- Prefer using a better name like `reversed` compared to `temp`, it tells more to the reader.
- Use `string.Empty` and not `""`

---

### Benchmarks

Your original code

```cs
        static public string Reverse(string s)
        {
            var names = s.Split(",");
            string temp = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = names[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    temp += names[i].ElementAt(j);
                }
                temp += i == names.Length - 1 ? "" : ",";
            }
            return temp;
        }
```

---

New

```cs
        static public string Reverse2(string s)
        {
            
            string reversed = string.Empty;
            foreach (var name in s.Split(','))
            {
                char[] NameArray = name.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(NameArray);

                reversed += new string(NameArray) + ",";

            }
            return reversed.TrimEnd(',');
        }
```

---

New2

```cs
        static public string Reverse3(string str)
        {
            StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var word in str.Split(','))
            {
                char[] singlesentence = word.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(singlesentence);
                reversed.Append(singlesentence);
                reversed.Append(",");
            }
            return reversed.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
        }
```

---

Note that I have `static` to use the function without an object reference.

I will use the following method to call the two functions multiple times, and benchmark it.

```cs
static void Perform(Func<string, string> Function, string names, int iterations, string type)
{

    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0;i < iterations;i++)
        Function(names);

    watch.Stop();

    var elapsed = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken for {type}: {elapsed} ms");
}
```

```cs
        static void Main()
        {
            string names = "Jack,Dylan,Bobby,Peter";
            const int iterations = 1000000;

            Perform(Reverse,  names, iterations, "Original");
            Perform(Reverse2, names, iterations, "New");
            Perform(Reverse3,  names, iterations, "New2");
       
        }
```

Here are the results

```cs
/*
" Release " Configuration

 Iterations  |   Original  |   New     |   New2
-------------+-------------+-----------+--------
 10 000      |    29   ms  |    5   ms |   5   ms
-------------+-------------+-----------+--------
 100 000     |    226  ms  |    54  ms |   43  ms
-------------+-------------+-----------+--------
 1 000 000   |    1763 ms  |    442 ms |   405 ms


*/
```

[Try it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pvzZry)

Comment: But why use a StringBuilder instead of simply filling a collection and then applying String.Join afterwards (this also does away with the ugly `.TrimEnd(',')`)? Especially considering this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585860/string-join-vs-stringbuilder-which-is-faster (Quite frankly, even if the performance of a StringBuilder was better, I'd still opt for the String.Join approach since it is more readable IMHO.)

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yeah that's true, the thing is String Builder is faster. If compactness and readability weigh-out performance in your project, you're welcome to use it :)

Comment: @BCdotWEB You mean using `string.Join(",", str.Split(',').Select(x => new String(x.Reverse().ToArray())));` right?

Comment: @BCdotWEB I've benchmarked the performance [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fgyt4h/). To me, the difference is too significant.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about Linq, so I decided to add a way to do it purely with Linq. This performs a bit worse than the StringBuilder examples, but is still *3x faster* than the original:

```
public static string ReverseWithLinq(string str)
{
    return string.Join(
        ',', 
        str
            .Split(',')
            .Select(w => new string(w.Reverse().ToArray())));
}
```

P.S. I would typically prefer using framework capabilities as much as possible, and only optimize further when necessary.

Comment: I just now saw this, thanks for posting this.